# goland: when i execute go mod tidy in goland,why "goproxy.io" is in the package url

Tags: goland

**go mod tidy in goland**

*bitbucket.org/xxxproject/db_proxy_api_model/models/v1 : cannot find module providing package.

reading https://goproxy.io/bitbucket.org/xxxproject/db_proxy_api_model/models/@v/list: 404 Not Found

server response:

not found: module bitbucket.org/xxxproject/db_proxy_api_model/models: git ls-remote -q origin in /tmp/gopath/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/cf011ef4494e04c40886924c664c719ff30fb53c96bff1250e26ef05478bbd13: exit status 128:

fatal: could not read Username for 'https://bitbucket.org': terminal prompts disabled.

Confirm the import path was entered correctly.If this is a private repository, see https://golang.org/doc/faq#git_https for additional information.*
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zcLio.png)

I set goproxy=https://goproxy.io,but its not the point, the problem is also appear in the case of dont use proxy.

**what can i do solving the problem**

Answer (score 0):

The project seems to be a private one and you should specify `GOPRIVATE` variable (https://go.dev/ref/mod#private-module-proxy-direct) via *Preferences/Settings | Go | Go Modules | Environment*. GoLand will be able to pick up the environment.